# I feel poor vs poorly

Tags: word-usage

Can I say: "I feel poorly" or do I have to say: "I feel poor" for "I feel ill"?
Or is it more correct to say:"I am poorly"?

Comment: Hello, Runrig. Please show what basic dictionary definitions are. Also, see njd's answer, and nohat's comment, [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211/well-and-good-as-applied-to-the-quality-of-photographs/216#216).

Comment: Very tired of every good questions being closed here. It's subjective authoritarianism about what people have the right to ask. Almost the same question has been asked here, without being closed.

Answer (score 8):

Using *[poorly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/poorly)* as an adjective means "unwell" or "somewhat ill," and you can certainly say "I feel poorly" to mean the same thing as "I feel ill."

"Poor" is an adjective with several different meanings, and if you said "I feel poor" it would most likely be taken to mean "I feel like I do not have enough money."

Saying "I am poorly" is not more or less correct, but it changes the meaning of the sentence. The difference between "I am poorly" and "I feel poorly" is the same as between "I am ill" and "I feel ill." It's possible to feel poorly without actually being ill, and vice versa.